# Generate absolute URL from an array of route components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
link_to 'My account', [:edit, :admin, :account, :details]
```

The code above does successfully resolve to the following relative path:

```
/admin/account/details/edit
```

Is it possible, using the same array, to render the absolute url? I.e.

```
mydomain.com/admin/account/details/edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use url_for:

```
link_to 'My account', url_for([:edit, :admin, :account, :details])
```

Check out this [document](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)

Comment: I had wished for that as well, but Rails wants me to set the host parameter. For which I'm trying to find out how/where. `"Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true"`

Comment: I assume I could add `default_url_options[:host]` in the environment config files, but if possible I'd rather provide the host directly on the `url_for`.

Comment: yeah you would set the host info in your config env!

Comment: I'm on Heroku and additional environments (e.g. staging) are set with variables, so that option would not work for me. Anyway, your answer is the Rails way.